# Why isn't PlayFramework recompiling my edited .java files properly?

Tags: java, playframework

I have been working with the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) for a few weeks now, and am really enjoying it.  Occasionally I have an issue come up which is frustrating me. It starts when I encounter a compile error.  I refresh, and see the (excellent) Play! error message.  Here's a simple example.

[image: example compiler error 1]

I go to the appropriate file, fix the error, and reload the page.  Then I get this compiler error:

[image: example compiler error 2]

Strangely, it shows the updated source code, with the bug fix, but it is throwing the same compiler error from the previous message. If I restart the Play! server, then everything compiles and I can go on as expected, but of course one of the great things about Play! is being able to edit .java source files and see those changes right away in the browser.

Would really appreciate a tip from anyone who's bumped into this before, or has a clue what is causing it! Thanks so much!  I am running OSX 10.6.

**EDIT**
I have also tried manually deleting the tmp/ directory, where the .class files are stored.  This does not help, and I get the same behavior, where the edited source code appears, but the old compiler error is still dsiplayed.

Comment: Is the behavior reproducible?

Comment: @niels; It occurs for periods of time, very reliably, and then goes away.  For example, it's already stopped happening since I posted this question.  But as I've been working the last week it comes and goes.  It will occur for half hour or so and I will have to restart the server for every compile error. Then, later, it will start reloading the classes properly, but I haven't been able to pinpoint what is causing or fixing the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

My best stab at this is that your clock is screwed up. Do you use time synchronization? Keep a terminal open running:

```
while true; do sleep 1; date; done
```

and check whether there is a correlation with clock changes and this behaviour.

FWIW, I've never witnessed this (also on MacOS 10.6)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! When I see the behavior next I will give this a shot.  I'm not familiar with "time synchronization", however.  What is that?

Comment: I'm getting the behavior again currently; I have a terminal open printing the date as you suggested, but I don't see anything abnormal there (time is right, matches displayed system time...).  Is there something particular I can look for?  Thanks for your thoughts @cdegroot!

Comment: Funny thing is, I saw it once myself a couple of hours after I answered :). I'll dig around, but it looks that something is cached that shouldn't be...

Comment: well at least now I know I'm not imagining things! I'm still seeing the behavior pretty regularly, but it comes and goes and I haven't found any intuition as to what causes it.  Let me know if you have any better luck than me!  I'll post here again if I can find the pattern that reproduces it 100%.

Comment: Play's framework code is quite clean - I'm going to add some debugging output there to see what's happening :)